# R function to count number of times when values changes

Tags: r, dataframe, data-science

I am new to R,
I have 3 columns named A1, A2, ChangeInA that looks like this in a dataset

| A1 | A2 | ChangeInA |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 20 | 10 |
| 24 | 30 | 24 |
| 22 | 35 | 35 |
| 54 | 65 | 65 |
| 15 | 29 | 15 |

The column 'ChangeInA' is either (A1 or A2)

I want to determine the number of times the 3rd column ('ChangeInA') changes.
Is there any function in R to do that?

Let me explain:
From the table, we can see that the 'ChangeInA' column switched twice,
first at row 3 and it switched again at row 5 (note that 'ChangeInA' can only have values of A1 or A2) so I want an R function to print how many times the switch happened. I can see the change on the dataset but I need to prove it on R

Below is a code I tried from previous answers

```
change<- rleid(rawData$ChangeInA == rawData$A1)
```

- This showed me all the ChangeInA

```
change<- max(rleid(rawData$ChangeInA == rawData$A1))
```

- This showed me the maximum number in ChangeInA

Comment: If you want to get help, it is often good to share data with the `dput` command and to give an example of the desired output (your explanation is not super clear) in a toy example.

Comment: Is the idea that we want to track which column ChangeInA matches (assuming only one), and then look at how often that reference column changes?

Comment: rle(df$ChangeInA==df$A1) can be a way. Please share a code example so an answer can be given.

Comment: `read.table` can be used with the provided data to generate the data in R (though would encourage amending this question to include `dput()` as well)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to use `rleid` from `data.table` to keep track of when a change occurs in `ChangeInA`, which we can use on a conditional of whether `ChangeInA` is equal to `A1`. Then, we can just use max to get the total number of changes.

```
library(data.table)

max(rleid(df$ChangeInA == df$A1) - 1)

# 2
```

Or we could use `dplyr` with `rleid`:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(rlid = rleid(A1 == ChangeInA) - 1) %>% 
  pull(rlid) %>%
  last()
```

**Data**

```
df <- structure(list(A1 = c(10L, 24L, 22L, 54L, 15L), A2 = c(20L, 30L, 
35L, 65L, 29L), ChangeInA = c(10L, 24L, 35L, 65L, 15L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```

Comment: Thank you, I think this works for me to an extent

Comment: @highclef I've updated the answer, as I think that is what you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you so much, It worked.
I have one more problem tho if you can help,
The 3 columns are just subsets of the data frame I'm working with,
I also have a Date-time stamp column, 
Now I want to create another column that will show the time interval in minutes between switching in the A1 and A2. please let me know if you don't understand my question. Thanks

Comment: @highclef I would create a new question for that. But be sure to provide your data and an expected output. In the new question, you can also link to this question to give more context.